# how to use an index route with useRoutes in React Router 6

Tags: react-router

```
<Route path="/exercises" element={<Layout />}>
  <Route index element={<List />} />
  <Route path=":id" element={<Exercise />} />
</Route>
```

How would I rewrite this as JS objects for `useRoutes()` including the index route?

```
{
    path: "/exercises",
    element: <Layout />,
    children : [
      {index? , element: <List />},
      {path: ":id", element: <Exercise /> }
 ] 
}
```

I'm not sure what to do with index...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useRoutes` hook takes an array of [`RouteObject` objects](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L807-L817)

> ```
> /**
>  * A route object represents a logical route, with (optionally) its child
>  * routes organized in a tree-like structure.
>  */
> export interface RouteObject {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: RouteObject[];
>   element?: React.ReactNode;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

You should be able to specify what is an index route using the `index` property.

```
{
  path: "/exercises",
  element: <Layout />,
  children: [
    { index: true, element: <List /> },
    { path: ":id", element: <Exercise /> }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
{
    path: "/exercises",
    element: <Layout />,
    children : [
      {path: "" , element: <List />},
      {path: ":id", element: <Exercise /> }
 ] 
}
```

When the path is /exercises Layout is Rendered and List is rendered in the Outlet in Layout. when the path is /exercises/4 (for example) the Exercise component is rendered in Outlet in Layout.